# Im having a problem of dependency with springboot-web-embed-tomcat it gives me the following error in log

Tags: maven, tomcat, dependencies

I have cleared and excluded every spring-boot-starter-tomcat from all spring-boot-starter-*anything* and still!

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.configureContext(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:367)

The following method did not exist:

    org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletContainerInitializer(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer;Ljava/util/Set;)V

The method's class, org.apache.catalina.Context, is available from the following locations:

    jar:.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.0.2/tomcat-embed-core-10.0.2.jar!/org/apache/catalina/Context.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.apache.catalina.Context: .m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.0.2/tomcat-embed-core-10.0.2.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.catalina.Context
```

after downgrading tomcat from 10.0.2 to 9.0.43 it also couldn't start and wrote application run failed and gave me the following stack trace:

```
ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
        at com.ebs.dda.config.ApplicationLauncher.main(ApplicationLauncher.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:451)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Since Tomcat 10 (Jakarta Servlet 5.0) the `javax.servlet` packages were renamed `jakarta.servlet`. Few libraries nowadays support the change, use Tomcat 9.0 instead.

Comment: changed it 9.0.43 and it gave me this error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start

Comment: There is surely a long stack trace with that error. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66336509/edit) your question and add the complete error message.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz i did so.

Comment: Don't you have any previous error messages in the log?

Comment: No I don't this is the only error